# Join two tables to get User.Name

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm developing a WCF RESTful service with C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and Entity Framework Code First.

**These are my tables**:

[image]

I want to select this on database:

```
SELECT PostLine.UserId, PostLine.Description, PostLine.DateUtc, User.Name 
FROM PostLine, User
WHERE User.UserId == PostLine.UserId
```

**And adding a filter for PostLine.DateUtc**.

Now, I do this:

```
DateTime fourDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-4);

var postLines =
    context.PostLines.Where(p => DateTime.Compare(p.DateUtc, fourDaysAgo) > 0);
```

But my problem is that I don't know how to join `User` table to get `User.name`.

**How can I join User table to get User.Name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `PostLine` class has a property of `User` type:

```
public class PostLine
{
    // your properties

    public User Author { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
string authorOfFirstPostLine = context.PostLines.First().Author.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime fourDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-4);

var postLines =
    context.PostLines
             .Join(context.User,
                   p => p.UserId,
                   u => u.UserId,
                   (p, i) => new {p.UserId, p.Description, p.DateUtc, u.Name})
             .Where(p => DateTime.Compare(p.DateUtc, fourDaysAgo) > 0);
```